# Create a multiple messenger chat from the API

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I want to create a "social" service of meetings between groups of strangers.
Since people do not know each other before meeting, I wish they could communicate before and especially before the appointment in case someone wants to prevent a delay or can not find others, or is first come on the scene for example...

This service would be accessible on the Web (no mobile application).

I told myself that integrating an available solution "offsite" would be a good idea because it allows to be used also on the phone. I thought of Messenger that is convenient because everyone or almost has facebook.

My idea is that people who sign up for a meeting are automatically added to a messenger group (or at least if the API does not allow it to create a group chat link they can join of their own chief...)

I have researched the API messenger and I have not found for the moment a way to create a group with Facebook IDs eg targeted.

Do you know if this is possible or something that has come closer in case it is not ?
for example a bot that creates a chat link with the users affected by the event ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Messenger API is for communication between Pages and (single) Users only. There is no API for User to User chats. You would have to create your own solution - Node.js with Socket.IO is perfect for that, for example.